# Crash when open three time 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Expression 0 + 0.0291667*0 + 0.00277778*369 unable to find variable UIWindow:

Tags: ios, swift, ios12

This crash happens in a `UINavigationController` for three times (present and dismiss consequently for 2 times after the first open).

I made a debug by using breakpoints and I figured that it happens in the presented ViewController after the `viewWillAppear` finish and before the `viewWillLayoutSubviews`.

However, it didn't stop between my lines of code so I can't detect the cause of the error.

**Happens in IOS 12 ONLY (Works fine in IOS 13)**

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Expression 0 + 0.0291667*0 + 0.00277778*369 unable to find variable UIWindow:0x7fb745603f60.minX{id: 21963} in engine 0x0'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000011709929b __exceptionPreprocess + 331
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000116635735 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000117099022 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 98
    3   Foundation                          0x0000000112f5bc10 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInFunction:file:lineNumber:description:] + 166
    4   Foundation                          0x000000011317221b -[NSISLinearExpression addVariable:coefficient:] + 341
    5   UIKitCore                           0x000000011ccb8166 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) nsli_lowerAttribute:intoExpression:withCoefficient:forConstraint:onBehalfOfLayoutGuide:] + 3120
    6   UIKitCore                           0x000000011ccb7527 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) nsli_lowerAttribute:intoExpression:withCoefficient:forConstraint:] + 289
    7   Foundation                          0x000000011317e0d3 -[NSLayoutConstraint _lowerIntoExpression:reportingConstantIsRounded:] + 96
    8   Foundation                          0x000000011317a3e8 -[NSLayoutConstraint _containerGeometryDidChange] + 117
    9   UIKitCore                           0x000000011cca33fa _UIViewEnumerateConstraints + 710
    10  UIKitCore                           0x000000011ccb10bc __57-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _switchToLayoutEngine:]_block_invoke_2 + 315
    11  Foundation                          0x000000011316555a -[NSISEngine withBehaviors:performModifications:] + 110
    12  UIKitCore                           0x000000011ccb0f5a __57-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _switchToLayoutEngine:]_block_invoke + 572
    13  UIKitCore                           0x000000011ccb0ce6 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _switchToLayoutEngine:] + 217
    14  UIKitCore                           0x000000011ccb1056 __57-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _switchToLayoutEngine:]_block_invoke_2 + 213
    15  Foundation                          0x000000011316555a -[NSISEngine withBehaviors:performModifications:] + 110
    16  UIKitCore                           0x000000011ccb0f5a __57-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _switchToLayoutEngine:]_block_invoke + 572
    17  UIKitCore                           0x000000011ccb0ce6 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _switchToLayoutEngine:] + 217
    18  UIKitCore                           0x000000011ccb1056 __57-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _switchToLayoutEngine:]_block_invoke_2 + 213
    19  Foundation                          0x000000011316555a -[NSISEngine withBehaviors:performModifications:] + 110
    20  UIKitCore                           0x000000011ccb0f5a __57-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _switchToLayoutEngine:]_block_invoke + 572
    21  UIKitCore                           0x000000011ccb0ce6 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _switchToLayoutEngine:] + 217
    22  UIKitCore                           0x000000011ccb1056 __57-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _switchToLayoutEngine:]_block_invoke_2 + 213
    23  Foundation                          0x000000011316555a -[NSISEngine withBehaviors:performModifications:] + 110
    24  UIKitCore                           0x000000011ccb0f5a __57-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _switchToLayoutEngine:]_block_invoke + 572
    25  UIKitCore                           0x000000011ccb0ce6 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _switchToLayoutEngine:] + 217
    26  UIKitCore                           0x000000011ccb1056 __57-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _switchToLayoutEngine:]_block_invoke_2 + 213
    27  Foundation                          0x000000011316555a -[NSISEngine withBehaviors:performModifications:] + 110
    28  UIKitCore                           0x000000011ccb0f5a __57-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _switchToLayoutEngine:]_block_invoke + 572
    29  UIKitCore                           0x000000011ccb0ce6 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _switchToLayoutEngine:] + 217
    30  UIKitCore                           0x000000011d1d6075 -[UIScrollView _switchToLayoutEngine:] + 106
    31  UIKitCore                           0x000000011ccb1056 __57-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _switchToLayoutEngine:]_block_invoke_2 + 213
    32  Foundation                          0x000000011316555a -[NSISEngine withBehaviors:performModifications:] + 110
    33  UIKitCore                           0x000000011ccb0f5a __57-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _switchToLayoutEngine:]_block_invoke + 572
    34  UIKitCore                           0x000000011ccb0ce6 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _switchToLayoutEngine:] + 217
    35  UIKitCore                           0x000000011ccafd4d -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _initializeHostedLayoutEngine] + 209
    36  UIKitCore                           0x000000011cca1712 -[UIView(UIConstraintBasedLayout) _layoutEngine_windowDidChange] + 130
    37  UIKitCore                           0x000000011d4da793 -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 170
    38  UIKitCore                           0x000000011d4da9ab -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 706
    39  UIKitCore                           0x000000011d4cd091 __45-[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:]_block_invoke + 151
    40  UIKitCore                           0x000000011d4ccf70 -[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:] + 804
    41  UIKitCore                           0x000000011d4dd9a5 -[UIView(Internal) _addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:] + 1951
    42  UIKitCore                           0x000000011d0d17f1 -[UINavigationTransitionView transition:fromView:toView:] + 627
    43  UIKitCore                           0x000000011d0b63a6 -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] + 3189
    44  UIKitCore                           0x000000011d0b6857 -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 896
    45  UIKitCore                           0x000000011d0b7bac -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 150
    46  UIKitCore                           0x000000011d04363f -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 217
    47  UIKitCore                           0x000000011d4e4015 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 1441
    48  QuartzCore                          0x0000000114fb6d3d -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 175
    49  QuartzCore                          0x0000000114fbbbf7 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 395
    50  QuartzCore                          0x0000000114f34aa6 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 342
    51  QuartzCore                          0x0000000114f6bc2a _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 576
    52  UIKitCore                           0x000000011cdf48f5 _afterCACommitHandler + 268
    53  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000116ffc037 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
    54  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000116ff64ce __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 430
    55  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000116ff6b61 __CFRunLoopRun + 1537
    56  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000116ff6221 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 625
    57  GraphicsServices                    0x000000011c65e1dd GSEventRunModal + 62
    58  UIKitCore                           0x000000011cdcb115 UIApplicationMain + 140
    59  Almtaar                             0x000000010d43a1ab main + 75
    60  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000118e83551 start + 1
    61  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: "I figured that it happens in the presented ViewController after the viewWillAppear finish and before the viewWillLayoutSubviews" Correct. What's crashing is the autolayout engine. Your autolayout constraints are bad.

Comment: @matt but this crash only Happens in iOS 12 ??

Comment: Hey did you find the solution to this problem?